# Why reactor design pattern named reactor?

Tags: design-patterns

We can check the original paper describing reactor design pattern.

[reactor-siemens.pdf](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-siemens.pdf)

> The Reactor design pattern handles service requests that are delivered concurrently to an application by one or more clients. Each service in an application may consist of several methods and is represented by a separate event handler that is responsible for dispatching service-specific requests. Dispatching of event handlers is performed by an initiation dispatcher, which manages the registered event handlers. Demultiplexing of service requests is performed by a synchronous event demultiplexer.

But I still can not understand why it is named reactor? What does reactor mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you know, there are two important participants in the architecture of Reactor Pattern:

1. Reactor: A Reactor runs in a separate thread, and its job is **to react** to IO events by dispatching the work to the appropriate handler.
2. Handlers: A Handler performs the actual work to be done with an I/O event

**What does reactor mean?**

Reactor is to react to incoming IO events and take appropriate action to it.

Consider, a **reactor** like a telephone operator in a company who answers calls from clients and transfers the line to the appropriate contact.

Consider a **handler** like an actual officer in the company the client wants to speak to.

Source:

https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-reactor-pattern-thread-based-and-eve